# Add mouseListener to Labels in Array Loop

Tags: java, loops, mouselistener

I want to add mouseListener to all labels in the array. Every label should show an other card of the layout. If I use below code, all labels show card6. What is wrong?

sorry this is correct code..

```
    panList = new JPanel();
    panList.setBounds(0, 0, 206, 517);
    panList.setLayout(null);
    cs.add(panList);

    CreateCards();

    int y = 0;  

        for(i = 0 ; i < 6; i++) {
        String lblName = getString("lbl"+String.valueOf(i));
        lblSettingTitle[i] = new JLabel("  "+lblName);
        lblSettingTitle[i].setBounds(0, y+10, 206, 26);
        lblSettingTitle[i].addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

                CardLayout cardLayout = (CardLayout) cards.getLayout();
                cardLayout.show(cards, "card"+String.valueOf(i));
            }
        });
        panList.add(lblSettingTitle[i]);
        y+=26;
        }
}

private void CreateCards() {
    card1 = new JPanel();
    card2 = new JPanel();
    cards = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
    cards.setBounds(206, 35, 814-206, 546-120);
    cs.add(cards);
    cards.add(card1, "card1");
    cards.add(card2, "card2");

}
```

Comment: `panList.setLayout(null);` isn't a good start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is when `mouse-event` fire value of `i` have value `6` or last value of `for-loop`

```
for (i = 0; i < 6; i++){}
```

you can create a `jlable` `class` and give a `instance` `variable` like `lableindex`
so when `mouse-event` occurs you first get the lable `index` and then show corresponding card.

or

you can getname of the jlable and get index by removing `lbl` part of the `jlable` name and show corresponding card.for example if jlable name is `lb12` then take 2 out and show card named `card + 2` or `card2`

for example consider this example

```
public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent e) {

        String index = ((JLabel)e.getSource()).getText().substring(xx,yy); // here xx , yy  depend on how you are naming jlables .this should return 2 if your lable is lbl2
        CardLayout cardLayout = (CardLayout) cards.getLayout();
        cardLayout.show(cards, "card" + index);
        System.out.println("card" + index);
}
```

Comment: in panList the labels are added. My cards are added in the Panel cards. I want to add in every label in the array a mouseListener. So label1 should show card1, ect

Comment: @coo12 what is panel list ?isn't it card layout container

Comment: no, it is the container for the label. card layout container is "cards"

Comment: thanks a lot, problem solved now. Problem was that the text in my Label is not equal with the name of my card. So it worked but the action was not performed because there wasn't a match. And I did not found a methode where I can get only the index[] of my Label. But now I solved it by loading a InputFile and getting the index from there.